# Keitsad tsolin mefarshim

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, maseches-pesachim

I need advice on mefarshim for the seventh chapter of pessahim keitsad tsolin. Most mefarshim left it.

I am looking for rishonim or kadmone achronim, like Pney Yehoshua.

Answer (score 2):

This link is to Meiri on chapter seven: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36400&st=&pgnum=121

And this is a link to Rashba on chapter seven:
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19207&st=&pgnum=44

Answer (score 1):

You can try here : [https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/משנה_פסחים_ז_א](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96_%D7%90).

And also here : http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_00880.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L5

You can find other books in the homepage of this site : http://www.ateret4u.com/online/a_root.html